# Use iframe within phonegap developer app

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I'm developing an hybrid app with cordova. For testing I use the Phonegap Developer App on mobile. This works great in most cases, but now I have a problem.

It seems that all iframes with external content stays empty within the the Phonegap Developer App on iOS. When I build the app to my iPhone the iframe with its content is displayed.

Is this an issue of the Phonegap Developer App which needs to fixed in order to make the iframe work within the Phonegap Developer app, or can I do something to make it work?

I want to use the iframe for youtube embeds for example.

Cordova version: 6.2.0
Following lines are in my config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Great! your question is answer of my question that i have been trying to solve for 3 days after work. I have the same problem. I can not display embedded youtube videos on IOS using Iphone developer App. I thought there is a problem with my code or configuration but looks like it was all about app!

My suggestion is don't waste your time. I did it for you :) and couldn't find any solution. let us know if you find solution.