# PhoneGap, iframe not work on iOS but do on Android

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, phonegap-desktop-app

I try this way:

> ```
>   <div id="contenedor">   
>   </div>
>   </body>
> <script>
> $('<iframe src="http://XXXXX.org/" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>').appendTo('#contenedor');
> </script>
> ```

or this way:

> ```
>  <body>
>   <div id="contenedor">
>        <iframe src="http://XXXXX.org/" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
>    </div>
>   </body>
> ```

Both works perfectly on Android but not on iOS. I'm using phonegap desktop 4.2.

I read all post about it here and changed config.xml many many times according the answers but nothing works on iOS.

Like:

> `<access origin="*"/>
>   <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>`

I changed this line too according other post but doesn't work too.

```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *
> 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; " />
```

I'm super stuck because works on Android but not in iOS.

Comment: Others report same problem unsolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841560/use-iframe-within-phonegap-developer-app I believe it is a matter with the developer app and the cordova-whitelist-plugin, but I don't know the exact reason it doesn't work.